# How to replace <li> tag in HTML with another tag and place it value in the new tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to update the following HTML to wrap each `<li>` with `<li><li-text>{li value}</li-text>`

```html
<ul><li>one</li><li>two<ul><li>three<ul><li>four<ul><li>five</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

hints: I ONLY USING JS, NO JQUERY

I'm trying this, but it's not working as expected!

```js
var html = `<ul><li>one</li><li>two<ul><li>three<ul><li>four<ul><li>five</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>`.replace(/<li[^>]*>/g,'<li><li-text>$&</li-text>')
```

The result I'm getting is not correct! the value of list should be between `<li-text></li-text>` tags!

```html
<ul><li><li-text><li></li-text>one</li><li><li-text><li></li-text>two<ul><li><li-text><li></li-text>three<ul><li><li-text><li></li-text>four<ul><li><li-text><li></li-text>five</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the expected result?

Comment: @InSync `<ul><li><li-text>one</li-text></li><li><li-text>two</li-text><ul><li><li-text>three</li-text><ul><li><li-text>four</li-text><ul><li><li-text>five</li-text></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>`
I need to wrap the text value only, not the whole nested list

Answer (score 1):

Forget about parsing HTML yourself. You can use the browser's built-in parser, select your `li` elements, and replace the content to be wrapped with `li-text`.

```js
const input = `<ul><li>one</li><li>two<ul><li>three<ul><li>four<ul><li>five</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>`

const parser = new DOMParser()
const doc = parser.parseFromString(input, "text/html")
doc.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.innerHTML = `<li-text>${li.innerHTML}</li-text>`)

const output = doc.body.innerHTML
console.log(output)
```

Comment: `Array.from()` is not necessary. `.querySelectorAll()` [returns a `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#return_value) which has a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the content as HTML, select all `<li>` elements, then replace each direct-children text node with a wrapper:

```js
function addWrapperToLi(html) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsed = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

  const textNodes = [...parsed.querySelectorAll('li')].flatMap(
    // .childNodes contains all kinds of nodes, including elements
    element => [...element.childNodes].filter(
      // ...but we only want text nodes.
      node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
    )
  );

  textNodes.forEach(node => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('li-text');
    wrapper.innerText = node.textContent;
    node.parentElement.replaceChild(wrapper, node);
  });

  return parsed.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function addWrapperToLi(html) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const parsed = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

  const textNodes = [...parsed.querySelectorAll('li')].flatMap(
    element => [...element.childNodes].filter(
      node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
    )
  );

  textNodes.forEach(node => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('li-text');
    wrapper.innerText = node.textContent;
    node.parentElement.replaceChild(wrapper, node);
  });

  return parsed.body.innerHTML;
}

const testcases = [
  '<ul><li>one</li><li>two<ul><li>three<ul><li>four<ul><li>five</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>',
  '<ul><li>one</li><li>two<ul><li>three<ul><li>four<ul><li>five</li></ul>after four</li></ul></li></ul>after two</li></ul>'
];

testcases.forEach(
  testcase => console.log(addWrapperToLi(testcase))
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```